# Linking to Image in Google Drive

Tags: image, google-sheets, hyperlink, drive

I have an app that links to a Google Sheet and 1 column of the Sheet has links to images on Google Drive.
These links worked as with the link:
**https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1wHFpogegcY3FMgXNM1pYFh-_9Vs3n73O**
but not the newest links such as:
**https://drive.google.com/uc?id=d/1_miFhLzYjf36ChdIjwRjryClwcJZazJ9/view?usp=sharing**
For some reason when I set access to Anyone with the Link and "Copy" the link, it adds this bit at the end, this extra tail:
**strong text**/view?usp=sharing.
Does anyone with more experience than I (most of you who are reading this) know
Is the last bit the issue?
Is the last bit necessary?
Why does the last bit appear when I Copy the link when it didn't previously?
Why was I able to do this some months ago, but now it doesn't work?
What is the correct method?
I didn't write this code, so I hope someone can explain this fairly simply.
Thanks for your ideas.
Tom

Answer (score 1):

The links you provided are Google Drive links to view files. The extra tail at the end, such as **/view?usp=sharing**, is indeed causing the issue, as it indicates that you are trying to access the file in a **preview mode**, which may not be accessible directly through your app.

What you should do:

- Format your link to: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/{file_id}/view](https://drive.google.com/file/d/%7Bfile_id%7D/view)

The {file_id} part will be a unique identifier for your file.

Replace {file_id} with the actual file identifier from your file's shareable link to create a direct link to the file. This link should work consistently and not change over time. Your app should then be able to access the images using this direct link without any extra tail or additional parameters.